# Successfully Install Artifactory RPM using Salt-Stack

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, salt-stack

I am working on fully automating some things using Salt Stack. I am currently working on installing Artifactory v5.3.2 using a RPM via Salt Stack. I am able to get this to install and work properly but begin getting a false-positive error from salt stack.

Currently running on `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)` with a masterless salt stack (just for testing purposes) from [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html). According to Artifactory documentation; they recommend using yum to install the rpm package.  [Installing Artifactory OSS from an RPM disribution](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-RPMorDebianInstallation).

I am aware of two salt-formula's for a similar use case but, these are over complicated for our needs. I attempted to post the two urls for them but don't have enough reputation for saltstack to allow me to do so.

After Downloading the rpm and placing it in the correct directory.. using this salt stack configuration does NOT work properly on the first attempt of an install:

```
jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch:
  pkg.installed:
    - source: salt://path/conf/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm
```

returning an error message like so:

```
ID: jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: Error occurred installing package(s). Additional info follows:`

         errors:
              - Running scope as unit run-2994.scope.
                Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
                Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
                 * base: mirror.steadfast.net
                 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
                 * extras: repo.us.bigstepcloud.com
                 * updates: mirrors.lga7.us.voxel.net
                No package jfrog-artifactory-oss available.
                Error: Nothing to do
 Started: 15:51:12.374898
Duration: 11271.36 ms
 Changes:
```

Using this configuration for salt:

```
jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch:
  cmd.run:
    - name: yum install -y /srv/salt/prod/path/conf/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm
```

Works the first time but, the second time running it using this format returns an error like so:

```
          stderr:
              Error: Nothing to do
          stdout:
              Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
              Examining /srv/salt/prod/path/conf/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm: jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2-50047.noarch
              /srv/salt/prod/path/conf/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm: does not update installed package.
```

Now, not to make things confusing.. if I have artifactory installed, and I then revert back to the first method of installing this using the `pkg.installed` method, things work as expected returning a success message saying '*All specified packages are already installed*'.

Typically this false positive is caused by not using the correct name of the package in the salt state file so running `yum list installed` returns `jfrog-artifactory-oss.noarch` ensuring I am using the correct naming in the salt state.

I am looking to have this work successfully regardless of if it is updating the package or not; without needing to over complicate our set up with the salt formulas provided.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use `- sources` (in plural) as a parameter for the `pkg.installed`. Also the package name is probably `jfrog-artifactory-oss` without `.noarch`. Last part an architecture for the package which, if I remember correctly, is not a part of the package name.

Comment: So when using the `- sources` I get an error stating: Invalidly formatted 'sources' parameter. See minion log.. Which when checking the minion log appears to give the same error. Even with changing the name to `jfrog-artifactory-oss`

Comment: It just doesn't seem to make much of any sense that after using yum to install the rpm, the pkg.installed method returns the result expected. but, when using the pkg.installed method on the first attempt to install does not work at all.

Comment: I am also having this issue with correctly installing a java jdk. Curious if possibly being caused by not having a true salt master. Might need to spin up a master and do some testing that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artifactory RPMs could be installed both using `yum` repository and `rpm` directly. Personally I would suggest using `yum` way as it makes future updates easier.

To answer your concern regarding using masterless setup - both options are fully functional in *masterless* as well as *master-minion* setups.

And one side-note. By default `pkg.installed` will try to use package manager native to your OS (`yum`/`rpm` in case of RedHat/CentOS). In most cases when installing package you should use it instead of calling `yum` or `rpm` directly.

**Using yum**

First thing we should do is to get `.repo` file holing information about `yum` repositories. Unfortunately, the one referred to in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-RPMorDebianInstallation) points to the repository with *pro* version of Artifactory. As we are interested in OSS - we should use a [different one](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-rpms)

To set it up we will first cook the `.repo` file with the following content:

```
[bintray--jfrog-artifactory-rpms]
name=bintray--jfrog-artifactory-rpms
baseurl=http://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-rpms
gpgcheck=0
repo_gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Now we should use salt to configure yum to use this `.repo` file and install Artifactory from this repository. Assuming that yum config file is located in salt tree under `files/jfrog-artifactory.repo`, Salt configuration will look as follows:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/artifactory.repo:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://files/jfrog-artifactory.repo

jfrog-artifactory-oss:
  pkg.installed:
     - require:
       - file: /etc/yum.repos.d/artifactory.repo
     - fromrepo: bintray--jfrog-artifactory-rpms
```

The `-fromrepo` option will make sure that the package is being installed using specific `yum` repository just in case it might be available in others.

**Using RPM**

It is also possible to download Artifactory RPM directly to your Salt configuration and install it from there. To do this I've used the following RPM file: https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-rpms/download_file?file_path=jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm . Assuming the file is downloaded into `files/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm` of your Salt tree, the state installing this package will look as follows:

```
jfrog-package:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - jfrog-artifactory-oss: salt://files/jfrog-artifactory-oss-5.3.2.rpm
```

Please note, that `-sources` part is a list of key-value pairs, where key is the name of the package and value is the path to the RPM file. Top-level `jfrog-package` is just a label

Comment: This, is exactly what I needed. I had mis-used the `- sources` the first time you had suggested it. Thank you for the help!